# VBA - Allocating multidimensional array directly using brackets

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find a practical way of directly allocating values to a multidimensional array in VBA without iterating. I Googled a solution which kind of works, but it fails when I try to use it in combination with variables..

This works:

```
Sub SomeSub()
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    vArray = [{"Zip", "22150";"City", "Springfield"; "State", "VA"}]

    For iCounter = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
        Debug.Print vArray(iCounter, 1), vArray(iCounter, 2)
    Next iCounter
End Sub
```

This, however, does not, and raises a "Type mismatch" error instead. The difference is that I try (and wish) to use variables instead of constant values:

```
Sub SomeSub()
    Dim vArray As Variant

    Dim iZip As Integer
    Dim sCity As String
    Dim sState As String

    iZip = 22150
    sCity = "Springfield"
    sState = "VA"

    Dim iCounter As Integer
    vArray = [{"Zip", iZip;"City", sCity; "State", sState}]

    For iCounter = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
        Debug.Print vArray(iCounter, 1), vArray(iCounter, 2)
    Next iCounter
End Sub
```

I find little or no information on this method for allocating arrays, so I'm hoping that someone has some insight to offer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA also has a built-in function called Array.  You can use Array within the Array function to make it "multidimensional."

```
Sub SomeSub()
    Dim vArray As Variant

    Dim iZip As Integer
    Dim sCity As String
    Dim sState As String

    iZip = 22150
    sCity = "Springfield"
    sState = "VA"
    vArray = Array(Array("Zip", iZip), Array("City", sCity), Array("State", sState))    

    Dim iCounter As Integer

    For iCounter = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
        Debug.Print vArray(iCounter, 1), vArray(iCounter, 2)
    Next iCounter
End Sub
```

Though the above code does answer the OP, I am editing this answer with more information.  Technically, this is not "multidimensional."  Rather, it is "jagged."  It's a Variant of a single-dimensional array of single-dimensional arrays.  In VBA, when you define a truly multidimensional array, you would use this syntax:

```
Sub someSub()
    Dim vArray(5, 5) As Long
    vArray(0, 1) = 5
    vArray(0, 2) = 3
    vArray(1, 3) = 4
    Debug.Print vArray(1, 3)   'Prints 4
End Sub
```

Another Stackflow user suggested this technical correction, and I wanted to incorporate that knowledge into the answer.

Comment: Well played, my friend.. Well played.

Answer (score 2):

The `[...]` syntax is a shortcut for `Application.Evaluate()` and as you have discovered it only works for runtime constant expressions, you can use a real call to `Application.Evaluate()` passing a dynamc string, but (*imo) thats quite hacky.

Alternatives:

- Create a factory function that accepts a `paramarray()` of arguments, step through it using a modulus counter to figure out what dimension to allocate to.
- As the first dimension appears to be a fixed string use a User Defined Type to allow `udt_var.City = "XXX" / udt_var.Zip = 12345 ...`
- Use a Collection (or Dictionary) which unlike the above is iterable (the latter by key).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I settled on writing a function using ParamArray to assemble the array.. I'm no fan of using Application methods.